# JavaScript reduce function code confusion?

Tags: javascript

In this code does obj refer to all the items in the array? Does obj[item] mean check if the "current item" is in the object (obj). If its not it assigns it 0, if it is it increments it by 1.

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car',
  'van', 'car', 'truck', 'pogostick'
];

const transportation = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  if (!obj[item]) {
    obj[item] = 0;
  }
  obj[item]++;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(transportation);
```

Comment: _In this code does obj refer to all the items in the array?_ - No, `obj` refers to the accumulator object and its initial value is an empty object which you passed to the `reduce` function as a second argument. _Does obj[item] mean check if the "current item" is in the object (obj). If its not it assigns it 0, if it is it increments it by 1_ - `obj[item]` checks if current item is present as key in the `obj`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the documentation: [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

The first argument of the function passed to reduce (obj) is the accumulator which in your case is `{}` you can set it with the second argument of the reduce method or it is defaulted as the first element of the array being iterated.

The second argument (item) is the current iterated element of the array,
the third argument is the current index and the fourth is a reference of the array being iterated itself (data).

Comment: obj is an empty object, how can an a current item be present in it?

Comment: because it is set in obj with  `obj[item]`.